# Does the MoodleCloud expose APIs that can be used by tools to integrate with it?

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I am looking for APIs that will let me sign in from the tool into the MoodleCloud and then access the objects in MoodleCloud for the account to be displayed and interacted with from the tool.

Comment: API for WHAT tool?

Answer (score 1):

No.

The only thing available for interaction are Official Moodle web services.

See https://docs.moodle.org/36/en/Web_services
and https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_service_API_functions